# Call multiple Zend view inside a layout ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have to create a theme in zend that have different sections like login section in side bar,users online different section in side bar and a main content area.

What I am thinking of is to create a different view.phtml files for each section and call it on zend layout.But I dont understand how to call a multiple views inside a layout.phtml in ZF2.

Comment: There you go: [Michael Gallego: How to replace the action helper in ZF2 and create great widgetized content](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/)

Comment: I have used the above code same as described in your above link.But I am getting a Fatal error. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for MeteoService' in

Comment: Check where the alias `MeteoService` is leading to, check Namespace, Classnames, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to run a different action for each widget, you can just split up the HTML and use includes like this:

```
<?php echo $this->doctype(); ?>

<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php include('includes/header.phtml'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->content?>
    <?php include('includes/footer.phtml'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need each widget to have different logic behind it, you'll have to use a setup like the one explained in the excellent article by Michael Gallego (mentioned by Sam).

Answer (score 0):

Call `<?= $this->render ('path/to/viewscript.phtml') ?>` (or `$this->partial`, refer to http://filip.forrez.net/2010/04/16/zend-framework-partial-and-render/) from your layout to render multiple view scripts.

However, note that all viewscripts you run will be executed within the context of the original controller/action. If you need an action to inject data into the view for a recurring widget, a sidebar for example, I usually create a class that extends `Zend_Controller_Action`, let's call it `Anup_Controller_Action` and then base all my view controllers on that class. In the `preDispatch` method of `Anup_Controller_Action`, inject the data into the view then. For example:

```
public function Anup_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function preDispatch ($options = null)
    {
         $this->view->loggedIn = true;
    }
}
```

Then when you call `<?= $this->render('shared/sidebar.phtml') ?>` from your layout or viewscript, you will always have access to the `$this->loggedIn` variable.